# Invoke google assistant device from command line instead of saying "Hey google"

Tags: google-api, google-home

Is there a way to invoke google assistant by executing a command (from a linux console) instead of saying "Hey google"?

I found a way, using nodejs, to send text to my home google mini to reproduce text, but I didn't find the way to enable the listening of it how I said "Hey google".

Comment: I found this package and there is an example in it that could lead to what you're looking for:

https://github.com/endoplasmic/google-assistant/blob/HEAD/examples/console-input.js